# Firebase Cloud Messaging API Auth error from APNS or Web Push Service

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am currently trying out firebase for the first time and after checking multiple youtube videos and google documentation, I still dont understand what is causing my issues for firebase error.

I am using the Node JS SDK of firebase but even after checking the documentation of google I am really stuck. Based on the documentation This simple code should work

```
require('dotenv').config()
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors');
const exp = express();
const MY_PORT = process.env.NODE_PORT || 3000;
exp.use(express.json());
exp.use(
    cors({
        origin: "*",
    })
);
exp.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    next();
});
const { initializeApp } = require("firebase-admin/app");
const { getMessaging } = require("firebase-admin/messaging");
initializeApp();
exp.post('/api/v1/send-push', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const registrationToken = req.body.token;

        const message = {
            notification: {
                title: 'My Title',
                body: 'Reminder'
            },
            token: registrationToken
        };

        // Send a message to the device corresponding to the provided
        // registration token.
        getMessaging().send(message)
            .then((response) => {
                // Response is a message ID string.
                console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log('Error sending message:', error);
            });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(500).json(err);
    }
})

exp.listen(MY_PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening on port ${MY_PORT}`)
})
```

It just uses an express js, then it should be able to connect to firebase library. But when I do try to send a json payload

```
{
    "token":"FCM_TOKEN_HERE",
    "title": "My App",
    "description": "Something for the description"
}
```

I always get this error. I have tried using the firebase notification test send to specific device and the push notification works correctly on my Flutter code and device for both IOS and Android but upon checking the nodejs code does not work.

```
Error sending message: FirebaseMessagingError: Auth error from APNS or Web Push Service
    at FirebaseMessagingError.fromServerError (C:\Users\MITCH-PC\Documents\fcm-express-server\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\utils\error.js:254:16)
    at createFirebaseError (C:\Users\MITCH-PC\Documents\fcm-express-server\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\messaging\messaging-errors-internal.js:35:47)
    at C:\Users\MITCH-PC\Documents\fcm-express-server\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\messaging\messaging-api-request-internal.js:79:75
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  errorInfo: {
    code: 'messaging/third-party-auth-error',
    message: 'Auth error from APNS or Web Push Service'
  },
  codePrefix: 'messaging'
}
```

Seeing there is also a possibility that we can use the FCM http request using http request to the FCM cloud messaging I also did try to follow and try if this is the case using OAuth stated on this blog.

https://medium.com/@ThatJenPerson/authenticating-firebase-cloud-messaging-http-v1-api-requests-e9af3e0827b8

But after trying I still have this different error

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 401,
        "message": "Auth error from APNS or Web Push Service",
        "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
        "details": [
            {
                "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.firebase.fcm.v1.FcmError",
                "errorCode": "THIRD_PARTY_AUTH_ERROR"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Would anyone be able to help me what I can check more or have experienced the same issue before? I have seen plenty of similar issues here and tried their solutions such as checking the configuration of firebase console but still it is not working.

Please Advise, Thank you!

Things Tried

- Checking firebase console configuration for APNs
- Tested the FCM Test push for specific device
- FCM HTTP API

Comment: Same issue, any update on this?

Comment: Some of your code is of the Legacy API and some is of the V1 API.  The Jen Person article is a good starting point however the response module she used back then is now deprecated - an alternative module is required.  My question featuring code I wrote is [ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77755017/should-a-successfully-sent-fcm-payload-receive-a-confirmation-id-http-v1-api?noredirect=1#comment137089671_77755017 ]